# what does "theme" and "come out" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> But I do a lot of expert witness testimony 
>   What's your recommendation for handling cross-examination
>   [LAUGH] Specifically, specifically a hostile one.
>   I feel like I'm being cross-examined.
>   It's very hostile.
>   [LAUGH].
>   In any speaking situation that you go into that has some planned element to it I
>   recommend identifying certain **themes**, that you think are important or
>   believe need to **come out**.
>   And then with each one of those themes have some examples and
>   concrete evidence that you can use to support it.

Answer (score 1):

I take "theme" here to mean 'idea" or concept" but that is not entirely clear from the quoted content.

I take "that you ...  believe need to come out" to mean ideas that the speaker wants to express to the audience, or to bring to greater attention. "Come out" in this sense is a common usage, indeed an idiom. It may derive from "come out into the light" meaning 'be exposed to public view" or 'be brought to public notice".

Comment: Wow, it's very helpful. Thank you so much.